# Cordova's plugins (screen-orientation / app-version) not working on Ionic 5 / Angular 11

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic-framework

**EDIT - TL DR;**

I have two plugins `cordova-plugin-screen-orientation` and `cordova-plugin-app-version` that dont work on my app no matter what. The app was built on my android physical device.

I've found out that `cordova-plugin-ionic-webview` plugin is the reason for this error. When I remove it, both plugins work, but the app is hosted on 'android:///file_assets/www/', and I needed it on a specific domain.

When I reinstall this plugin, the app is hosted on the right domain, but both plugins stop working again.

---

I'm struggling to solve one specific issue regarding ionic and cordova's plugins.

I'm trying to install both cordova-plugin-screen-orientation and cordova-plugin-app-version following Ionic's documentation below:

- https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/screen-orientation
- https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/app-version

My issue is that both plugins have been successfully installed under my project, but they do not work nor give any kind of warn / error on chrome's devTools.

For example, screen-orientation plugin does get called by my code, and I can detect onChange events when switching portrait / landscape orientations (I'm using a physical android device for testing), but the `this.screenOrientation.lock(this.screenOrientation.ORIENTATIONS.LANDSCAPE)` function that I need does nothing. The same applies for `unlock()`

As for app-version, when I call `this.appVersion.getAppName()` (happens with all functions), the promise never gets resolved, giving me no answer whatsoever.

**Here's** `ionic info` (I'm using npm 7.15.0 by the way):

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 6.14.1 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.6.8
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.1102.13
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 11.2.13
   @angular/cli                  : 11.2.13
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 3.1.1

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 7.1.0
   Cordova Platforms : android 7.1.4
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 5.0.0, (and 7 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res : 0.15.3
   native-run  : 1.3.0

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (/home/diego/Android/Sdk)
   NodeJS            : v14.17.0 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm               : 2.15.12
   OS                : Linux 5.3
```

**Here's** `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "myApp1",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "https://ionicframework.com/",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --ssl true --ssl-key /node_modules/browser-sync/lib/server/certs/server.key --ssl-cert /node_modules/browser-sync/lib/server/certs/server.crt",
    "lab": "ionic serve --ssl true --ssl-key /node_modules/browser-sync/lib/server/certs/server.key --ssl-cert /node_modules/browser-sync/lib/server/certs/server.crt --lab",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^11.0.2",
    "@angular/common": "^11.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^11.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^11.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^11.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^11.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^11.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/action-sheet": "^5.26.0",
    "@ionic-native/app-rate": "^5.33.0",
    "@ionic-native/app-version": "^5.33.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.33.0",
    "@ionic-native/device": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/ionic-webview": "^5.33.0",
    "@ionic-native/launch-review": "^5.26.0",
    "@ionic-native/native-storage": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/screen-orientation": "^5.33.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/user-agent": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic/cli": "^6.15.0",
    "@ionic/lab": "^3.0.0",
    "@ionic/storage-angular": "^3.0.6",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^9.1.1",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^2.0.1",
    "add": "^2.0.6",
    "cordova": "^9.0.0",
    "cordova-android": "^8.1.0",
    "cordova-ios": "^5.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^6.0.0",
    "core-js": "^3.13.0",
    "es6-promise-plugin": "^4.2.2",
    "sw-toolbox": "^3.6.0",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "^0.1102.4",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1102.4",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "^11.0.0",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "^11.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^11.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^11.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~11.0.0",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^3.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^15.0.3",
    "angular2-template-loader": "^0.6.2",
    "browser-sync": "^2.26.7",
    "codecov": "^3.6.5",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-app-version": "^0.1.12",
    "cordova-plugin-apprate": "^1.7.2",
    "cordova-plugin-dialogs": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^5.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-nativestorage": "^2.3.2",
    "cordova-plugin-screen-orientation": "^3.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.3",
    "html-loader": "^0.5.5",
    "jest": "^24.1.0",
    "null-loader": "^0.1.1",
    "postcss": "^8.2.15",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "rxjs": "6.6.3",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.6.7",
    "sonar-scanner": "^3.1.0",
    "ts-loader": "^3.5.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.3",
    "typescript": "~4.0.0",
    "webpack": "^4.46.0"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "platforms": [
      "ios",
      "android"
    ],
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {},
      "cordova-plugin-nativestorage": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-apprate": {
        "PLAY_CORE_VERSION": "1.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-screen-orientation": {},
      "cordova-plugin-app-version": {}
    }
  }
}
```

**And here's also the code that actually calls those plugins:**

**login.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';

import { AppVersion } from '@ionic-native/app-version/ngx';

import { LoginPageRoutingModule } from './login-routing.module';
import { LoginPage } from './login.page';
import { HeaderPageModule } from '../header/header.module';
import { FooterPageModule } from '../footer/footer.module';

import { ScreenOrientation } from '@ionic-native/screen-orientation/ngx';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
     CommonModule
    ,FormsModule
    ,TranslateModule
    ,ReactiveFormsModule
    ,IonicModule
    ,LoginPageRoutingModule
    ,HeaderPageModule
    ,FooterPageModule
  ],
  declarations: [LoginPage],
  providers: [
    ScreenOrientation
    ,AppVersion
  ]
})
```

**login.page.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import { AlertController, Platform } from '@ionic/angular';
import { ScreenOrientation } from '@ionic-native/screen-orientation/ngx';
import { AppVersion } from '@ionic-native/app-version/ngx';

import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';

import { Alias } from '../interfaces/metadata_project';
import { LoadingUtility } from '../utilities/loading-utility';
import { Utilities } from '../utilities/utilities';

import { AppRateService } from '../providers/apprate-service';
import { LoginService } from '../providers/login-service';
import { SessionService } from '../providers/session-service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.page.scss']
})
export class LoginPage implements OnInit {
    //some variables....
  constructor(
    //...
     private _screenOrientation: ScreenOrientation
    ,private _appVersion: AppVersion
    //...
  ) {
  }
 
  public async ngOnInit() {
    this._appVersion.getAppName().then(
      (res) => {
      console.log('ENTROU'); // Never gets called....
      console.log(res);
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);      // Nothing here also...
    });

   
    this._screenOrientation.lock(this._screenOrientation.ORIENTATIONS.PORTRAIT).then(() => {
    console.log('TRAVOU'); // Does get called, but I can still switch orientation...
      }).catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);    //Nothing here...
    });;
```

**What I've tried so far:**

1. Delete node_modules / package_lock.json, and `npm install`
   everything again, plus `ionic cordova platforms add android`.
2. Downgrade cordova 10 --> 9 / 8 / 7.
3. Downgrade Node.js 16 --> 14 / 12.

Can anyone shed some light into this issue? I have no idea on how to debug / detect any installation issues at the moment.

Comment: Please share your git repo here to check and reproduce the issue.

Comment: There you go: https://github.com/Diegomatosguedes/StackOverflow-post

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to solve my issue by upgrading from Cordova, to Capacitor v3.

As it turns out, the Capacitor framework doesn't need the "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview" plugin, so it's safe to remove it from it's architecture. And since it was this plugin which was not compatible with the other two, my issue was solved.

Also, the functionallity of this plugin still is delivered by Capacitor.